# Where to Place/Manage files in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is When i create class
     My_loader extends CI_Loader

why there is a need to place it in a folder application/core
Can i place it some other folder?

i am finding difficulties in understanding the flow of CodeIgniter 
how the classes are loaded automatically from the right diretories by
just writting this line
     $this->load->function()

i hope i made my question clear
Please any help will be great
PS: i am a newbie at any framework so pardon my question and english if you thinks its a amateur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an **application** folder and a **system** folder in codeigniter.

System folder contains the files of codeigniter which is the necessary files of codeigniter to function and is not recommended to change these files.

Application folder is for you. You can add your own controllers, views, models, libraries, helpers etc.. there. If you want add some functionality to codeigniter base classes u can do it by creating the corresponding file in application folder. for example if u want to add some functionality to codeiniter security class (which is found in system/core/Security.php) you can do it without changing system files by creating My_security.php in application/core/ directory.

Codeigniter has a well planned directory structure. u can see codeigniter libraries in system/libraries/ and like that your libraries are placed in application/libraries/

U can see the request flow of codeigniter from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html

Codeigniter has a very good documentation (goto http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide)

Comment: Thanks for The help,i am starting to get a much clear picture now,one more thing, do i need to prefix my custom classes with "MY_"

Comment: when u are extending core classes core class and its filename must be prefixed with MY_ , you can use your own prefix by setting $config['subclass_prefix'] in config file in application/config . Your controllers, models and views need not to prefix with that. see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 1):

> Every time CodeIgniter runs there are several base classes that are
>   initialized automatically as part of the core framework. It is
>   possible, however, to swap any of the core system classes with your
>   own versions or even extend the core versions.
>
> Most users will never have any need to do this, but the option to
>   replace or extend them does exist for those who would like to
>   significantly alter the CodeIgniter core.
>
> Note:  Messing with a core system class has a lot of implications, so
>   make sure you know what you are doing before attempting it.
>   from [codeigniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Now what you need to know is that codeigniter uses a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to generate its classes, at post-system running phase, and you can take a look into the workflow in `/system/core/Codeigniter.php` file

and by `$this->load->.....` this is called an autoloader, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634003/how-does-codeigniters-load-work) is a good explanation about it.

Another important note to be taken is:

CodeIgniter does not apply the rules of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) but it uses a [FrontController Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) so just to take it in mind that it when you are learning codeigniter you are far away from MVC

Comment: I feel that this answer is some kind of misguided for those who just wants to learn MVC. Front controller pattern how you manage your incoming request from a single point which you can add in your MVC. From that context, learning codeIgnitor is not really contrasting with the MVC contest.