# Loader.php connection to My_loader.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, classloader

i have a very basic question regarding Code Igniter loading
how MY_loader (specifically) connected to loader.php

for example

if i try to create a class in application/core

```
    class custom_class extends CI_Loader {
           Public function template(){
                      do something; 
               } }
```

such declaration that doesn't serve the purpose  the function never gets called
but when i create class under the name

```
         class custom_class extends CI_Loader {
              Public function template(){
                    do something; 
           } }
```

the classes it loaded automatically
and the function can be called
so what i am interested in the generic steps involved in the whole process

or what is happening behind the scenes 
em sure there is not such thing as automatic there must be some code for it

Any help in this regard is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you are missing here is [Simple four OOP principles](http://www.4inv.com/delphi/oo.htm) and some elementary [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

First of all let's address this code,

```
<?php
class Human {
    var $name;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Son extends Human {
    function speak() {
        return "singing lullaby";
    }
}

class GrandSon extends Son {
    function speak() {
        return "baby laughing";
    }
}

$humans = array(new Son('Mamdouh'), new GrandSon('Emma'));

foreach($humans as $human) {
    print $human->name . " is: " . $human->speak() . '<br>';
}
?>
```

As you can see, even that `class Son` and `class GrandSon` has no `$name` attribute, still we get to use it as a property in their instances, and that's what we call [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)
Which is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types. and that's how the extends in your loader case works, now, How does the `CI_Loader` works, as I already mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121659/where-to-place-manage-files-in-codeigniter/20121918#20121918) that the loader is a [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

**Disclaimer:** the link I provided for the Factory Pattern is a Factory Method Pattern and Not [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), which is not completely relevant to the question.

but the Idea here is the same, a Factory is responsible of generating/[instantiating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantiation)  class objects to separate this process from the [domain logic/Business Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic)
which will make code testing easier.

Apparently, there are lot of readings to do, but it is more than simple to be understood.

**Note:** You can check the written code above in this [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xgf-txk)

Comment: Thank you very much your answer really helped and i believe u have lots of knowledge in CI  and Design patters which i am currently lacking your answer really helped me in understanding

Comment: but one think em failing to understand why declaring class with name MY_loader only works, why can;t i use a different name  i have tried it but the class name other than MY_Loader doesn't work ... CI looks for a file name MY_Loader

Comment: I think it's more like what you said. CI might be looking into file names inside a folder then apply some stupid rules on it to guess the class name. But this is not effective nor efficient. But as it works with you. That's what you need to know.  :-D